# Why is the hover effect overlapping?

Tags: html, css

When I mouseover the button, the hover effect is over-lapping the icon and label of the button. I tried to move the layer of the icon/label divs on top of the hover effect by putting the `z-index: 999;` and it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div class="service-wrapper">
    <div class="services">
        <a href="#"><div class="button">
            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/?id=42205&size=36" class="iconBtn">
            <div class="serv-name">TECHNICAL SUPPORT</div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
        <a href="#"><div class="button">
            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/?id=7495&size=36" class="iconBtn"> 
            <div class="serv-name">CUSTOMER SERVICE</div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffbb11; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

 a {
    text-decoration:  none;
} 

.button::before,
.button::after {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}

.button::after {
    height: 70px;
    left: -22%;
    top: 0;
    transform: skew(50deg);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transform-origin: top;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.button:hover:after {
   height: 60px;
   width: 325px;
}

.iconBtn{
   max-height: 85%;
   max-width: 85%;
}

img:hover: {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

See [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/0zr5ed7v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you attached the `z-index:999` to the `img:hover` meaning that you have to hover the image for it to apply. Also you added an extra `:` after `img:hover` so it was like `img:hover:`.

Furthermore, adding `z-index:999` to the label does actually solve the problem. You see the result here:

```css
.button {
 height: 40px;
 width: 230px;
  margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffbb11; 
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}
 a {
  text-decoration:  none;
}
.button::before,
.button::after {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
}

.button::after {
 height: 70px;
 left: -22%;
 top: 0;
 transform: skew(50deg);
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transform-origin: top;
 width: 0;
   z-index: 0;
}
.button:hover:after {
 height: 60px;
 width: 325px;
}
.iconBtn{
 max-height: 85%;
 max-width: 85%;
    z-index: 999;
}
.serv-name{
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
    <div class="service-wrapper">
    <div class="services">
        <a href="#"><div class="button">
            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/?id=42205&size=36" class="iconBtn">
            <div class="serv-name">TECHNICAL SUPPORT</div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
        <a href="#"><div class="button">
            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/?id=7495&size=36" class="iconBtn"> 
            <div class="serv-name">CUSTOMER SERVICE</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. I originally had `.button .iconBtn{ z-index: 999;}` and `.button .serv-name{ z-index: 999;}` and that didnt work either. Thanks so much clearing up!

Comment: Well I cant see why that wouldn't work - perhaps they were placed after the `img:hover:` part or Something else with an error which could have caused a malfunction